# Redundant if statement warning in haskell

Tags: haskell, if-statement, warnings

So I'm following the tutorial [Learn you a Haskell for Great Good!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions) and so far I absolutely love Haskell.  But in one of the functions mentioned in the tutorial I'm getting a warning that the if-statement is redundant.

Edit: Let me be clear, the intent of the function is to act exactly the same way the elem function works (the one that is provided with Haskell by default).

Here's the original function:

```
elem' :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool  
elem' y ys = foldl (\acc x -> if x == y then True else acc) False ys
```

Originally there were two warnings, one was eta reduction, so I removed the ys from the beginning and end of the function name to arrive at:

```
elem' :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool  
elem' y = foldl (\acc x -> if x == y then True else acc) False
```

Now I tried to reduce the function to the following and it results in an error:

```
elem' :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool  
elem' y = foldl (\acc x -> x == y)
```

I think I'm just very new to Haskell and can't see the obvious solution.  Can someone tell me what code change would keep the function working correctly and yet remove the compiler warning?

Comment: Compiler warnings or compiler errors?

Comment: @MattFenwick Until the last typed in function, they are only warnings, but the last one is an error, and won't compile.

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example? I've tried your very first function with `ghc -Wall` and don't get any warnings mentioned.

Comment: @maksenov well, I'm writing it in eclipse using the eclipseFP plugin and I'm working on a windows system.  Could that be why you don't get a warning?  Plus, the warning is just eclipse underlining it with a yellow line, which I believe is more accurately described as a suggestion from "HLint" if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Asaf HLint is basically taken as gospel amongst Haskellers.

Comment: @Dan Burton I can't tell if this is sarcasm or not, but alright.  I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`if x == y then True else acc` is the same as `x == y || acc`.

Comment: Switching to `foldr` also lets it work on infinite lists. `elem' y = foldr (\x acc -> x == y || acc) False`. `elem' 3 [1..] ==> True`

Comment: This is indeed the very suggestion that HLint produces; not sure why Eclipse would drop this info.

Comment: Thank you for the correct answer, and yes, I don't know why Eclipse doesn't include it.  I do know this though, EclipseFP does NOT come with HLint automatically, I had to run cabal install HLint (or something like that) to install it.  So perhaps I misspoke when I said eclipse was grabbing the info from HLint.  My apologies if this is the case.

Answer (score 4):

Typing your last definition into `GHCi` without a type annotation:

```
Prelude> let elem' y = foldl (\acc x -> x == y)
Prelude> :t elem'
elem' :: (Eq b) => b -> Bool -> [b] -> Bool
```

It doesn't match your declared type.

You forgot the `False` at the end!  If you add it in:

```
Prelude> let elem' y = foldl (\acc x -> x == y) False  -- note the False at the end
Prelude> :t elem'
elem' :: (Eq b) => b -> [b] -> Bool
```

It has the right type!

Comment: That certainly explains why there is an error, but how would I remove the warning without causing this error, or any other? Edit: Looks like the right answer now, thank you

Comment: @Asaf -- does this code `elem' y = foldl (\acc x -> x == y) False` cause warnings?

Comment: unfortunately I can't check it at the moment, but I will when I get back to my computer, thank you for your help

Comment: It has the right type, but does not behave like `elem`. `elem' [3,1] 3` produces `False`; since the accumulator is ignored, this function is essentially the same as `elem' y xs = last xs == y`

Comment: @DanBurton -- I interpreted the question as `how do I get this to compile/give me no warnings?` .... I didn't even consider it from the point of view of writing a meaningful function.  Do you think I should edit my answer?  I'm not really sure about this.

Comment: @MattFenwick Well, I'm unsure.  This question was just made because I'm trying to learn Haskell and couldn't get a simple function to work without some warning.  I thought the answer would help me to learn Haskell, which it has.  But if you can't make the function act like elem should, don't worry about it.  It's not very important.  I'll probably use the knowledge provided to try and make it work one way or another.  I'm pages past this portion in the online book anyway.

Comment: @MattFenwick so your solution does indeed remove the compiler warnings, and it provided more details and helped me learn more, but as pointed out it doesn't act like elem should after that.  For that reason I'm not choosing your answer, but thank you very much for your help .

Comment: @Asaf -- you should add that (that you want it to act like `elem`) into the OP; the OP doesn't mention it at all -- it only asks for help with compiler warnings/errors.

Comment: @MattFenwick my apologies, I will do that now